# on image click not working jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a images on my html page and I am trying to make it so when the image is clicked an alert box pops up. I dont understand why my js isnt working.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="canvas">
  <div id="cinematic-overlay"></div>
     <img src="img/characters/RodgerRiddle.png" id="rodger "alt="" width="60px" height="40px">
</div>
```

This is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#canvas').on("click", "#rodger", function (e) {
    alert('hi'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: This is just a typo - you have a space after the `id` in `rodger`.

Comment: everybody sometimes has a typo so try to use something like Prettier or so

Answer (score 6):

> You have a `space` character in your markup and while selecting element using `id` selector, space is not considered, which will not select the target element.

Remove space from `HTML markup`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#canvas').on("click", "#rodger", function(e) {
    alert('hi');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas">
  <div id="cinematic-overlay"></div>
  <img src="img/characters/RodgerRiddle.png" id="rodger" alt="" width="60px" height="40px">
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for downvote, I misunderstood your answer (thought about space between function and (e) which you removed), I have reverted the downvote

Comment: @pwolaq, No problem ;)

Comment: @Rayon thanks for this however, i copy and pasted your answer exactly and i still have no luck in producing an alert box

Comment: @Rayon I see that :( i dont understnad why mine isnt i copy and pasted it exactly, this. I dont know why mine isnt working

Comment: @seus, Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)  so that one can debug that ?

Comment: ill do my best to share it

Comment: @Rayon i sent you my code not sure why its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113912/discussion-between-seus-and-rayon).

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that this is caused by "cinematic overlay" which may be overlapping the image, making it unable to click

to check this, you can add `cursor:pointer` to image and see if it changes when you put mouse over it

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#rodger').click(function(){
    alert('Hi!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas">
  <div id="cinematic-overlay"></div>
  <img src="img/characters/RodgerRiddle.png" id="rodger" alt="" width="60px" height="40px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

write it like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rodger").click(function(){
    alert("#rodger was clicked.");
 });
});
```